# "cannot resolve symbol" in espresso source

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

see my screenshot, here is my [full code](https://github.com/roroco/ro-h/tree/cannot-resolv-symbol-in-espresso-source)

[image]

I have add guava in build.gradle, but it still doesn't work, how to make android studio resolv "com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull"

Answer (score 0):

when i add guava and restart android studio, it work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10928790)

Comment: @Will This (albeit inadequate) answer *is* by the question poster.

Comment: Thanks, missed that!

@pozklundw, can you please expand your answer just a bit, and then mark it as accepted?